# How to apply elvis operator in Thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

how to apply a ternary condition that Elvis Operator in Thymeleaf.

I tried this but there is an error showing in IDE. the error `Tag start is not closed`

```
<div th:utext="${ed.aurl} ? '<button th:href="@{ed.aurl}" target="_blank" download>View Attachment </button>' : 'No Attachment' "></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't/can't use HTML in attributes like that (it's expecting a valid HTML doc)... why not write this as regular HTML?

```
<div>
  <button th:if="${ed.aurl}" th:href="@{ed.aurl}" target="_blank" download>View Attachment</button>
  <span th:unless="${ed.aurl}">No Attachment</span>
</div>
```